# Can I connect directly to a Redis server from JavaScript running in a browser?

Tags: javascript, redis, rest

I know there are node.js libraries for Redis; what I'd like to do is run a Redis server (either on localhost or on a server host somewhere) and call it directly via HTTP (i.e. AJAX or HTTP GET as needed) from JavaScript running inside a browser (i.e. a Greasemonkey or Chrome Extension script, or maybe a bookmarklet or SCRIPT tag). Does Redis have a native REST or HTTP API?

Comment: I'm considering asking this question again, but stipulating we want a 'real' as in realtime redis-client -- not HTTP anything -- operating in the browser.  Could build a great realtime 'infrastructure' with just CDN serving assets constituting the client webapp communicating with Redis directly.  I want to cut out the unnecessary WebSocket server aspect of the system.  All the control logic can be internalised to redis cluster in Lua.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241247/what-would-it-take-to-implement-a-good-redis-client-in-the-web-browser

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't connect directly to Redis from JavaScript running in a browser because Redis does not speak HTTP. What you can do is put [webdis](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis) in front of Redis, it makes it possible work with a Redis instance over a HTTP interface.

Comment: Currently there is no Windows implementation: https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis/issues/138

Answer (score 4):

You can literally connect to the redis server over http, and there's a security exploit based on this.

> Redis is effectively a HTTP server
>    -- http://benmmurphy.github.io/blog/2015/06/04/redis-eval-lua-sandbox-escape/

Maybe this could be used to make a javascript client for redis? In the examples shown, commands are sent directly to the redis server, which executes them. However, practically speaking, you can use openresty+nginx in front of redis to essentially directly talk to redis over http, and get the performance benefit of nginx's multithreaded server which will share a limited set of connections to redis itself.

Answer (score 2):

As @Theo explained, you can't connect directly, but if you have webdis and redis set up then I have a library that eliminates mucking around with ajax yourself, in favor of a promises based approach.

[webdismay](http://npmjs.com/package/webdismay) is a JS library I have recently released (License: MIT) to connect to a webdis+redis backend from the browser.  It takes an ES6 Promises approach to communicating with the redis+webdis back end, providing [functions](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/DrPaulBrewer/webdismay/) for generic and keyless redis commands and organized classes for commands that operate on [Keys/Strings](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/DrPaulBrewer/webdismay/class/src/index.js~Key.html), [Lists](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/DrPaulBrewer/webdismay/class/src/index.js~List.html), [Hash](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/DrPaulBrewer/webdismay/class/src/index.js~Hash.html) and [Sets](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/DrPaulBrewer/webdismay/class/src/index.js~Rset.html).  All functions/methods return ES6 Promises.

Assuming you have webdis set up with redis, in the default configuration to accept post requests to "/", then with webdismay a simple example of sending data to the server and getting it back later would look like this on the browser (in ES6):

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';  // fetch polyfill
import * as W from 'webdismay';
const k = W.key('some-redis-key');
k.set('Hello, World!');  // store the information
// wait a while, e.g. in the dev console or with setTimeout()
k.get().then((v)=>console.log(v));  // --> Hello, World!
```

At the time I am writing this (July 2016), the first two `import` lines require some translation and packaging assistance from tools like jspm or browserify (if you change the `import` to `require`).

This is not exactly beginner-friendly, yet, but could allow someone to use webdis+redis from the browser without constantly translating mentally between javascript idioms and redis and writing their own ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Webdis is very very slow as compared to using an NGINX server in front of redis

If you just implement a simple redis client in mod-perl and expose behind nginx, you can easily get very good performance. And you can handle a lot of logic too

Comment: As the author of Webdis and having done *many* benchmarks of Webdis and alternatives, I strongly disagree with this statement. Webdis is multi-threaded and easily able to saturate a single-threaded Redis instance which quickly becomes the bottleneck in a benchmark. When I was developing Webdis I had discussions with the author of the [Redis nginx module](https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module) and we both came to the conclusion that Webdis was faster. Additionally, the suggestion to use mod-perl is highly unlikely to lead to better performance than using Webdis – quite the opposite.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the original question ("Can I connect directly to a Redis server from JavaScript running in a browser?" / "Does Redis have a native REST or HTTP API?") but rather a response to another answer. As such, it is better suited as a comment on that answer.