# Connecting directly to redis with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, redis, predis

This is referring to a previous post made on Stackoverflow asked 3 yrs ago ([Connecting directly to Redis with (client side) javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311984/connecting-directly-to-redis-with-client-side-javascript)). Are there any updates on how to call redis pub/sub from Javascript? (Other than the webdis option the chosen answer showed). I have a redis php script that is able to subscribe from php but I am having trouble calling from Javascript and getting the response. I have tried making a ajax get with jquery and it times out. Any updates would be helpful.