# how to call an exe from a web page (HTML, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, redis

I want to link JavaScript with a C++ component using Redis. How can I use redis to call an exe (C++) from a web page (HTML, JavaScript)?

Comment: By which means does it matter that the program was written in c++?

Comment: No, Actually I have developed my component in C++

Comment: Do you want to execute the program at the client machine or server side?

Comment: actually i am developing a system on my local machine. I want to use redis database to call an exe from a web page.

Comment: You are to create a proxy for you C++ program, any kind of API server to use it from HTML and JS (via AJAX)

Comment: I want to use redis

Comment: This is not a C++ related question (it should contain what your question is about "callid an exe from a webpage"). C++ does not matter at all

Comment: Is the C++ code (exe) on the clients machine or on the server?

Comment: You obviously can't *call* an exe from a webpage - for security and portability reasons. One way would be to have the exe running on your machine and listening to http requests from your webpage. Alternatively, you can compile C++ into WebAssembly that your page can run, see [emscripten](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/).

Comment: its on client side

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759120/can-i-connect-directly-to-a-redis-server-from-javascript-running-in-a-browser) for info on js -> redis communication. [Here](https://redis.io/clients#c--) is a list of redis clients for C++. Maybe you want some kind of event store architecture. Your question is a bit broad for this format, I'd recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS, you can configure an ISAPI CGI to run this.

Here some example how to do this:

https://blogs.iis.net/thomad/how-to-run-a-cgi-program-under-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5