# connecting redis via POSTMAN

Tags: redis, postman, postman-collection-runner

Is it possible to connect redis db via postman, What I am trying to do is I am creating a test suite where I am Executing multiple testcases for that I am passing the test file via collection runner there I am passing the redis configuration values also,

I want to connect to redis first, and then execute the lpush for inserting into db, can we do this using postman?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/5759345/11900243

Answer (score 3):

No.
Postman only supports the HTTP protocol.
You must use a third party tool to access the redis via http protocol.
ex) https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis