# Redis cache with React.js

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, redis

I am new to Redis, and my application is written in React.js(front-end) and Kotlin(back-end). My question is, redis cache connection is made at React.js side or Kotlin side?

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be done in your back-end side. Your front-end may communicate with your redis cache via using your back-end's endpoints.

[Redis's security documentation](https://redis.io/topics/security)

[Another post about similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759120/can-i-connect-directly-to-a-redis-server-from-javascript-running-in-a-browser)