# JavaScript to Redis ? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Please help. I read a lot and looked for solutions but I was more confused. I am developing an application with the GOOGLE GeoLocation API.
The whole logic is in JavaScript. My idea is for each user to see the rest of the map. For this purpose, I have to save the coordinates of each user in Redis / Memcache (two-dimensional array) but I have a problem with connecting JS with Redis. I also saw that many others have a track problem. And I wonder about that.
Is this the best way?
Is there another way?
And if that's the way I'm wrong?

I have only this.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Redis client connected');
});

client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong ' + err);
});
```

With this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "redis" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at Object.s [as require] (require.js:5)
    at requirejs (require.js:5)
    at home:165
```

[error one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVkIR.png)

I added [... ] and the error is

[error two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oznLJ.png)

Comment: Error message `Module name "redis" has not been loaded yet` means that you did not `npm install` any of the `redis`'s packages

Comment: let's try to check this install manual page: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use Redis with Node.js.

You can find all the recommended libraries for Node.js here https://redis.io/clients#nodejs, they are marked with a star. On every library documentation you will find examples for simple usage!

It seems that you want to use the node-redis library, be sure to install the library with `npm install redis` (it seems to be the specific you are dealing with) and then try the basic example here: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#example. Maybe you will need to read this https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#rediscreateclient to provide your Redis connection settings in order to create a working client.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and detailed answer, but I still can't figure out where the problem is.
In the node_modules folder, I have express and rediss. It works through the console but gives these errors in the browser.

I forgot to mention that the application is Laravel and is on a server (online)
https://followme.folirpolir.com/


Please help, I have been reading for a week now and I always reach a dead end.

Comment: I don't totally understand what you are trying to achieve. The answer I gave you previously is about communicating with Redis in a Node.js environment, which is not the same as the browser.

Usually, the classical architecture design is to create an adapted HTTP API on the backend that communicates with your DB and makes it possibles for the frontend to retrieve some data and/or perform actions. However, there are some tools that can directly add an HTTP interface to your Redis, you can read more about this here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5759345/4561420

Comment: I might be wrong and wrongly interpret your comment, but it appears to me that you are confused about the difference between Node.js and the browser. You might want to search and learn more about what Node.js is and how does it differ from a browser before solving your initial problem (with a fresh point of view!).

Comment: I want to show all users of my app on this map in real time.


Because over time there will be more users and a lot of queries to the database, I decided to use REDIS to save and share the coordinates of each. Is this a good idea?


And I'm really confused what technologies I should use

This is the google API and all its logic is in JavaScript so I just need a way / place to save the coordinates of the users.

Comment: It may be a frustrating answer, but I insist on recommending you to learn more about how to build a simple web service and how they are organized.