# TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null (svelte redis)

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, svelte

I just got started with svelte and was trying to make an app with redis as the db. I made a typescript file with all the db functions I would need and tried to import it into my svelte components, but when I did that I got the following error

```
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-L35TFNQI.js?v=60c87e0f:6515:46)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-VP3FZ6LR.js?v=60c87e0f:25:44)
    at node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-L35TFNQI.js?v=60c87e0f:9192:20)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-VP3FZ6LR.js?v=60c87e0f:25:44)
    at node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/index.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/redis.js?v=60c87e0f:852:20)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-VP3FZ6LR.js?v=60c87e0f:25:44)
    at node_modules/redis/dist/index.js (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/redis.js?v=60c87e0f:2589:20)
    at __require (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-VP3FZ6LR.js?v=60c87e0f:25:44)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/redis.js?v=60c87e0f:2615:21
```

This is my redis file (even with only this much, I get the same error)

```
import redis from 'redis'

export var str = "sample string"
```

This is my svelte component's script

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { str } from "../redis_test";
</script>
```

Comment: ok, i tried to import redis directly into the svelte component and i am still getting the error

Comment: @Shoejep thanks for the info, I am looking into that now, but I wanted to ask you, is this the correct way to fetch data from a database, or do people do something else, like are we supposed to make a REST API for this on the backend or something?

Comment: [Can I connect directly to a Redis server from JavaScript running in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759120/can-i-connect-directly-to-a-redis-server-from-javascript-running-in-a-browser) Normally, you would have a server side that connects to the database.

Comment: @Shoejep thanks a lot, so just to make sure I got everything right, what people normally do is, have a server side which connects to the database, and the front end makes requests (REST/GraphQL) to the server (backend) which handles those requests appropriately

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right to me

Comment: @Shoejep okay, thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, because the [redis - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) package is designed for Node.js, I would say to follow [How to use npm modules in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562978/how-to-use-npm-modules-in-browser-is-possible-to-use-them-even-in-local-pc) and use `browserify` so that it's able to run in the browser.

After reading [Can I connect directly to a Redis server from JavaScript running in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759120/can-i-connect-directly-to-a-redis-server-from-javascript-running-in-a-browser), I would say that you need a server-side setup to connect to your redis server and then you can query your server-side as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and my understanding from reading the above is that it caused because the browser client is trying to read the db which is on the server.
I am also using sveltekit and I resolved by problem by making sure my code was in an endpoint, which only runs on the server and then invoked the endpoint to get my data.